# SASS error when compiling

Tags: css, sass

Does anyone have any ideas why I'm getting this error when using compass watch and compiling this SASS code?

> /* Error: Invalid CSS after "...176b, vertical)": expected expression
>   (e.g. 1px, bold), was "; // IE6-9"
>           on line 2 of assets/sass/theme.sass

```
body {
  @include filter-gradient(#0b0039, #2b176b, vertical); // IE6-9
  @include background-image(linear-gradient(top, rgba(11,0,57,1) 0%,rgba(40,22,99,1) 65%,rgba(43,23,107,1) 100%));
}
```

I also get it on the includes if I remove the `background-color` so not sure what's happening here.

Comment: You'd need to tell us what `filter-gradient` is before we could answer that.

Comment: James, would you update this question, as per Andrei's suggestion? Thanks.